# Pagination without having different urls to each page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm scraping a web (using Python requests and requests-html modules) and I need to go through all the pages of a list of items.

In "human user" world, I click either in the "2" for second page, or in "->" to go from actual to next page.

When I inspect the elements I just said, they are a `<div>` tag such as:

`<div class="pagination__Page..."> 2 </div>` or

`<div class="pagination__Page..."> -> </div>`

Both with an `event` linked to each, so that when I click on it, moves to the following page.

I've tried to do the for loop pagination suggested by requests-HTML documentation but it doesn't work in this case, because there are no links associated to the `r.html` object, nor to each page of the list.

When I click, in the website, on those "divs" the url does not change at all.

Inspecting the `event` (for the `2` case) it calls a JS function, such as:

```
function() {
   return a({
      pageNum: e
   })
}
```

Inspecting the `event` function (for the `->` case) it calls a JS, such as:

```
function() {
   return a({
      direction: "right"
   })
}
```

I want to get the same result as when clicked, but I don't know how.

Comment: a couple ways to do this come to mind. 1) Use Selenium to simulate opening the browser, process the html, then have it "click" on next page and repeat. 2) if you share the url, we could see if it gets the data from XHR. And if it does, it is possible you can get the data through POST request, where the page number is part of the query paramter, and you can iterate it through that way.

Comment: in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox you can see all requests sent to server. You can check request sent when you click next page and then you can try to do the same request with python..

Comment: @chitown88, if for query parameter you are talking about the parameters sent in the url, I don't think it could be possible (or at least, I don't know how to do it) since, as I said earlier, the url doesn't change after clicking 'next page'. Nevertheless the url is: [link](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/arrivals/ORY/?year=2019&month=4&date=29&hour=6)

. furas, I don't think there is such a request, it seems to be a somehow full pre-loaded list, that is shown in chunks of 25 rows.

Comment: No, I wasnt referring to the url. I was referring to the xhr (if there is one). I’ll take a look tomorrow since I’m not near my laptop til then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use the dev tools to get the precise query parameters (specifically the `rqid`), but this should get you going. It'll return the full list, without need to go page by page:

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://www.flightstats.com/v2/api-next/flight-tracker/arr/ORY/2019/4/29/6'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

query = {
'carrierCode': '',
'numHours': '6',
'rqid': '7tl8o43bkps'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query).json()

df = json_normalize(jsonData['data']['flights'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                  airport.city  ...                                                url
0                      Cayenne  ...  /flight-tracker/TX/571?year=2019&month=4&date=...
1    Saint Denis de la Reunion  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/671?year=2019&month=4&date=...
2               Pointe-a-Pitre  ...  /flight-tracker/SS/3541?year=2019&month=4&date...
3               Pointe-a-Pitre  ...  /flight-tracker/TX/541?year=2019&month=4&date=...
4                       Moscow  ...  /flight-tracker/S7/4021?year=2019&month=4&date...
5                       Moscow  ...  /flight-tracker/ZI/516?year=2019&month=4&date=...
6                      Cayenne  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/853?year=2019&month=4&date=...
7                      Cayenne  ...  /flight-tracker/KL/2245?year=2019&month=4&date...
8                     Toulouse  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/6101?year=2019&month=4&date...
9               Pointe-a-Pitre  ...  /flight-tracker/KL/2261?year=2019&month=4&date...
10                    Toulouse  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5101?year=2019&month=4&dat...
11              Pointe-a-Pitre  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/793?year=2019&month=4&date=...
12                      Beirut  ...  /flight-tracker/SS/6628?year=2019&month=4&date...
13                      Beirut  ...  /flight-tracker/ZI/628?year=2019&month=4&date=...
14                 Montpellier  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/7541?year=2019&month=4&date...
15                      Geneva  ...  /flight-tracker/U2/1399?year=2019&month=4&date...
16                 Montpellier  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5541?year=2019&month=4&dat...
17                     Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/4442?year=2019&month=4&date...
18                      Bastia  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/7780?year=2019&month=4&dat...
19                     Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/7770?year=2019&month=4&dat...
20                     Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/XK/770?year=2019&month=4&date=...
21                      Bastia  ...  /flight-tracker/XK/780?year=2019&month=4&date=...
22                      Bastia  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/4458?year=2019&month=4&date...
23                   Marseille  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5001?year=2019&month=4&dat...
24                   Marseille  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/6001?year=2019&month=4&date...
25            Clermont-Ferrand  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/7433?year=2019&month=4&date...
26            Clermont-Ferrand  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5433?year=2019&month=4&dat...
27                    Bordeaux  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5253?year=2019&month=4&dat...
28                    Bordeaux  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/6253?year=2019&month=4&date...
29                        Nice  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5203?year=2019&month=4&dat...
..                         ...  ...                                                ...
192                  Marseille  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5009?year=2019&month=4&dat...
193                    Sevilla  ...  /flight-tracker/TO/3201?year=2019&month=4&date...
194                   Bordeaux  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/6277?year=2019&month=4&date...
195                   Toulouse  ...  /flight-tracker/U2/4026?year=2019&month=4&date...
196                   Toulouse  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5117?year=2019&month=4&dat...
197                   Toulouse  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/6117?year=2019&month=4&date...
198                       Rome  ...  /flight-tracker/IB/5193?year=2019&month=4&date...
199                       Rome  ...  /flight-tracker/VY/6251?year=2019&month=4&date...
200                   Bordeaux  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5277?year=2019&month=4&dat...
201                       Faro  ...  /flight-tracker/U2/4278?year=2019&month=4&date...
202                   Campinas  ...  /flight-tracker/AD/8900?year=2019&month=4&date...
203                 Casablanca  ...  /flight-tracker/AT/760?year=2019&month=4&date=...
204                   Campinas  ...  /flight-tracker/ZI/36?year=2019&month=4&date=2...
205                       Rome  ...  /flight-tracker/U2/4242?year=2019&month=4&date...
206                    Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/XK/772?year=2019&month=4&date=...
207                    Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/4445?year=2019&month=4&date...
208                    Ajaccio  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/7772?year=2019&month=4&dat...
209                     Madrid  ...  /flight-tracker/AV/6049?year=2019&month=4&date...
210                     Madrid  ...  /flight-tracker/AA/8758?year=2019&month=4&date...
211                     Madrid  ...  /flight-tracker/IB/3436?year=2019&month=4&date...
212                      Setif  ...  /flight-tracker/AH/1108?year=2019&month=4&date...
213                     Berlin  ...  /flight-tracker/ZI/608?year=2019&month=4&date=...
214                     Berlin  ...  /flight-tracker/SS/6608?year=2019&month=4&date...
215                     Toulon  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/7513?year=2019&month=4&date...
216                     Toulon  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5513?year=2019&month=4&dat...
217                  Perpignan  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/7465?year=2019&month=4&date...
218                  Perpignan  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5465?year=2019&month=4&dat...
219                      Rodez  ...  /flight-tracker/BE/7682?year=2019&month=4&date...
220                     Nantes  ...  /flight-tracker/AF/7383?year=2019&month=4&date...
221                     Nantes  ...  /flight-tracker/HOP/5383?year=2019&month=4&dat...

[222 rows x 13 columns]
```

Comment: chitown88, I'm trying to reproduce the code above using the "original path" (https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/arrivals/ORY/?year=2019&month=5&date=5&hour=6) and when I hit the `jsonData = requests.get(url_address, headers=headers, params=query).json()` line, I get a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. Any idea of why is that? and how to avoid it (besides using your link xD, ofcourse) Thanks.

Comment: the original path returns a response as html. In contrast to the other link from the api, which return in a json format. So when you're trying to parse the html as `json`, it'll throw the error since it's not a valid json format/structure.